# Failed to execute (RastertoPolygon) Syntax error at or near symbol SPACE

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-010328

I'm converting series of raster to polygon using RastertoPolygon in arcpy.

```
#import the module
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.overwriteOutput = True

#set the workspace
env.workspace = r"C:\thesis\for sampling\sampling_outputs\raster_per_biogeoregion"

#Get a list of rasters and convert to shapefile
for raster in arcpy.ListRasters("*Luzon_*.tif", "TIF"):
    print raster #check the presence of rasters
    arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(raster, raster.replace("tif", "shp"), "NO_SIMPLIFY")
print "Finish converting all the rasters to polygon"
```

After several checks on the syntax, formatting, I've always been stuck with this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\brentiebark\Dropbox\Python Scripts and          mxds\batch_convert_raster_to_polygon_simple.py", line 14, in <module>
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(raster, raster.replace("tif", "shp"), "NO_SIMPLIFY")
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 178, in RasterToPolygon
raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 010328: Syntax error at or near symbol SPACE.
ERROR 010267: Syntax error in parsing grid expression.
Failed to execute (RasterToPolygon).
```

Are there things that I missed from this code?

Comment: I think it is complaining about the space in your pathname "for sampling" - perhaps rename the folder to be called "for_sampling" and try again.

Comment: I changed it to "for_sampling" but the same error message returned.

Comment: @user35246. What does `raster` print as just before the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error in your "RastertoPolygon" script is due to a space in the file name of one or more of your input rasters. To confirm this answer, I ran your script on a folder of raster files and it worked perfectly. I added a space to the file name of one of the rasters and it failed with the message "ExecuteError: ERROR 010328: Syntax error at or near symbol SPACE", which is the same error message that you got.

Arcpy does not allow spaces or periods in file names. Please make sure that none of your input file names have special characters like spaces or periods in them and try again.

Answer (score 0):

*I was getting this error as well:*

> ERROR 010328: Syntax error at or near symbol SPACE.
> ERROR 010267: Syntax error in parsing grid expression.

The solution is to change the directory of your input data or signature files! To make sure the appearing directories don't have any space between the names.

It worked for me!